# running pig on amazon emr is super slow

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, emr

I used AWSSDKforPHP to start a emr instance to run pig scripts, and foud it unbearably slow. if i run the same pig jobs on ec2 instance in pig local mode, it takes only 10 mins, if i start a emr to run the pig jobs in mapreduce mode, it takes couple of hours. this is strange. I used to run similar pig job on internal hadoop cluster in mapreduce mode, it's very fast. is there any config settings that i need to specify? i already set 1 master node and 4 slave nodes for the emr, still not enough??

thanks.

Comment: Can you see where the time is going? For instance, are your tasks waiting for available containers and then being released 1 by 1?